# Iterating many times through Text input value in the Reducer in a MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, iterable

I have **two very large datasets**(tables) on HDFS. I want to **join them** on some column(s), then **group them** on some column(s), and then **perform some group functions** on some columns.

**My steps are:**

> 1- Create two jobs.
>
> 2- In the first job, in mapper read the rows of each dataset as map
> input value and emit **join columns'    values** as map output key and
> **remaining columns' values** as map output value.
>
> After mapping, the MapReduce framework performs shuffling and groups
> all the map output values according to map output keys.
>
> Then, in reducer it reads each map output key and its values which man include
> many rows from both datasets.
>
> **What I want is to iterate through reduce input value many times so that I can perform cartesian product.**
>
> To illustrate:
>
> Let's say for a join key x, I have 100 matches from one dataset and
> 200 matches from the other. It means joining them on join key x
> produces 100*200 = 20000 combination. I want to emit NullWritable as
> reduce output key and each cartesian
> product as reduce output value.
>
> An example output might be:
>
> for join key x:
>
> From (nullWritable),(first(1),second(1))
>
> Over (nullWritable),(first(1),second(200))
>
> To (nullWritable),(first(100),second(200))
>
> **How can I do that?**
>
> I can iterate only once. And I could not cash the values because they dont fit into memory.
>
> 3-  If I do that, I will start the second job, which takes the first
> job's result file as input file. In mapper, I emit group columns'
> values as map output key, and the remaining columns' values as map
> output value. Then in reducer by iterating through each key's value, I
> perform some functions on some columns like sum, avg, max, min.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first MR job use join key as map output key, your 1st reducer will get (K join_key, List< V> values) for each reduce invocation. What you can do is just separate values apart into two separate list, each for a datasource, and use nested for loop to do cartesian product.

Comment: Henry, thank you for your reply. But how can I seperate them without fetching them into memory?

Comment: @digitalmert, I think the values has already fetched into memory, since they all exist in the List. Do you mean your both files are huge and cardinality of the join key is really small, and it would cause OOM error even with a dummy reducer?

Comment: Yes. Since a join key's value may include many rows from both files, the value may not fit into the memory. For a key x, the value may include millions of rows from oth tables. If I try to fetch one table's rows into memory then do cross production, this may cause out of memory error. For scalability reasons, I don't want to do that. Is there a way you can suggest for this case?